# I need help reassigning a variable in a bot menu

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to build a setup menu for my bot that the server owner can use to configure the bot. The menu is triggered when the owner types `=setup`. I want the bot to reply with several embed messages asking the user questions in order to correctly configure the bot.

This is my first `Discord.js` project so I am unaware of the syntax but trying to learn. I have a constant variable called prefix assigned to `=` when the bot is implemented into the server.

The first prompt on the bot menu asks the user to change the `prefix` to anything they want. I need help understanding how to reassign my original constant variable to the new prefix they are requesting.

```
var PREFIX = '=';

bot.on('message', message=>{
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'setup':
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('Step 1 of 1')
            .setDescription('Set your Prefix')
            .setColor(0xF1C40F)
            message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
            //I want the user to now enter their own PREFIX and have the
            //bot save their responce as the new PREFIX
        break;
    }
})
```

What I want to happen is when the user types their desired `prefix`, the bot will reassign `prefix` in the code, and delete the bots question and the users response and begin to prompt them with the next question.

Comment: Then the first step would be to *get the reaction*. What have you tried towards that?

Comment: I am very new and don't know what steps to take. Ive looked all over the Discord.js documentation API but don't know what I am looking for

Answer (score 3):

depending if your bot is going to be in multiple servers with different prefixes:

- If so then you need a database to save the prefix for each server and
  then get it when  a user sends a message from that server
- If not I would use a json file to store the prefix, then have node
  edit the file when it needs to change

Or look at https://discordjs.guide/keyv/ there is a great tutorial there to do what you want

Comment: also quick note, you can still use the database for a single server, it may be better but more complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can't `prompt` the user to respond (from what I know), you'll need to wait for the user to write another message and analyze it.

A message is linked to a user, so when a user initiates the command to change the prefix, you want to make sure that the **same** user changed the prefix.

This untested but should be close to the solution you're looking for.

```
let prefix = '=';
let expectingResponseFrom = null;

bot.on('message', message=>{

    // same user sent a response
    if(expectingResponseFrom !== null && expectingResponseFrom === message.user.id){
      expectingRepsonseFrom = null;
      prefix = message.content.trim();
      return;
    }

    const regex = new RegExp(`^${prefix}([^\s]+)`, 'g');
    cosnt command = regex.exec(message.content)[1] || '';

    switch(command){
        case 'setup':
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('Step 1 of 1')
            .setDescription('Set your Prefix')
            .setColor(0xF1C40F)
            message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
            // memorize user who initiated a prefix change
            expectingResponseFrom = message.user.id;
        break;
    }
})
```

The regex allows for a *better* (my opinion) way of getting the command

```js
console.log(
  (/^=([^\s]+)/g).exec("=hello should not get this"),
  (/^=([^\s]+)/g).exec("="),
  (/^=([^\s]+)/g).exec("= should not get this")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a database to store prefixes and other server settings, it's more efficient and stable than using a JSON file for example.

I suggest you use `mongoose` and/or just `MongoDB` if you're unsure as to what to use.